# Excel VBA pivot table boolean

Tags: vba, excel

The below VBA code should propose the user to input the month of the report, then update all the pivot tables accordingly. 
The issue I am facing is if the user input a month which is not one of the pivots items (i.e. "mayo" i/o "may") it will mess my pivot table. So i want to check if the string entered in the inputbox is one of the correct pivotItems.

I have an error message stating "object required"
I don't find what is wrong when I declare my bool.

Any ideas?

```
Sub ChooseMonth55()

Dim MyMONTH As Variant
Dim MyRepMon  As String
Dim Pi As Boolean
    Set Pi = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Test Month").PivotItems
    Pi = False
InputBoxMyMONTH:    MyMONTH = Application.InputBox("Enter the MONTH in a full text format")

    MyRepMon = MyMONTH

    Sheets("All results excl not tested").Select

    If MyRepMon = Pi Then
        MyRepMon = True
    End If

    If MyRepMon = True Then

        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MyRepMon
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MyRepMon
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MyRepMon
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MyRepMon
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MyRepMon
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = MyRepMon

    Else: MsgBox "There is a typo, please enter again the Month"
         GoTo InputBoxMyMONTH
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the point of setting Pi then making it false back to back like that?

Comment: It can be wrong sorry, I was thinking that we have to declare the boolean and set it to false for the code to work.

Comment: What kind of value ends up here?: 'ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Test Month").PivotItems'??

Comment: I want to declare Pi as all the possible pivot items, specifically it will be January, February, May, ....

Comment: I want to make sure that the result of the input box is one of the months in my pivot

Comment: If that is the case, you can't.  because you already declared Pi as a boolean.  Set another variable to store the month.

Comment: Updated my answer below to incorporate UserForms to limit the months to only what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would suggest you use a UserForm and a dropdown box**, or comboBox to **limit the user's input to ONLY the months you KNOW work**.

- Create a sheet, you can hide it.  Insert the months you want listed ONLY on it.
- Insert a UserForm
- Name it, Insert a ComboBox into it, and a Label.
- Set the Rowsource for the ComboBox in the Properties window to the Range where the Valid Month Entries are listed.

[image: SETUP 1]

[image: SETUP 2]

Now RIGHT CLICK the user form in the explorer window in VBA.
**Insert this code:**

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Call ChooseMonth(ComboBox1.Value)
End Sub
```

You can simplify your original code EVEN MORE now, because it's pulling the EXACT month, with no mistakes, unless you typed it wrong on the Month source sheet.

**Your Code:**

```
Sub ChooseMonth(myMonth As String)

    Sheets("All results excl not tested").Select

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = myMonth
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = myMonth
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = myMonth
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = myMonth
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = myMonth
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Test Month").CurrentPage = myMonth

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes indeed it will be the best option. thanks very much for the help.

Comment: I have become almost totally reliant on UserForms for this exact reason.  I am always trying to streamline the User Flow to the least resistance and errors.

Comment: On a side note, that is also how you call functions or subs by passing arguments.  In the comboBox event for if it changes, we pass the value of the comboBox through to your code, by putting what we expect in the () of the sub declaration.  The difference between Functions and Subs is that in a Function, you expect a result to get passed back into the code that it was called From.. .So you would call from one bit of code 'sum = AddTwoNumbers(x, y)' and expect to get back the sum.  It would be declared like this, 'Function AddTwoNumbers( x as Long, y As Long) As Long'

Answer (score 0):

Give this function a try. It determines whether a pivot item is in a specific pivot field inside a pivot table.

```
Public Sub Test_IsItemInPivotField()
  Debug.Print IsItemInPivotField("May", "Test Month", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1"))
  Debug.Print IsItemInPivotField("Mayy", "Test Month", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1"))   
End Sub

Public Function IsItemInPivotField(itemName As String, fieldName As String, pvt As PivotTable)
  Dim pvtItem As PivotItem

  For Each pvtItem In pvt.PivotFields(fieldName).PivotItems
      If pvtItem.Name = itemName Then
          IsItemInPivotField = True
          Exit Function
      End If
  Next

  IsItemInPivotField = False
End Function
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.